# Simple random walk expectation problem

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, random-walk, independence

Consider a simple symmetric random walk, $\left\{X_n\right\}$, where the following hold;
$$X_n = X_{n-1} + Y_n$$ for $n = 1, 2, 3,\ldots$

$$Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, \ldots \text{iid }, \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = 1) = \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = -1) = 1/2$$

$a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $-a \leq X_0 \leq b$,

$T$ is the time to absorption for a walk with absorbing barriers at $-a$ and $b$.

We let $\eta_k = \mathbb{E}(T \mid X_0 = k)$ and I wish to show

$$\eta_{k+1} - 2\eta_k - \eta_{k-1} = -2$$

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can deduce that
\begin{align}
\eta_k&=E(T\mid X_0=k)=1+\frac 12E(T\mid X_1=k-1)+\frac 12 E(T\mid X_1=k+1)\\
&=1+\frac 12 \eta_{k-1}+\frac 12\eta_{k+1}
\end{align}
This is the same as your equation, except for a minus sign. I think your equation is wrong, since is should be symmetrical in $\eta_{k-1}$ and $\eta_{k+1}$. (There is no way to distinguish going to the left or right).

To obtain this equation, we just calculate the expected absorbing time for the situation after the next move and add one to that for the current move.

Comment: I attempted use of the partition theorem.

$$\mathbb{E}(T | X_0 = k) = \eta_k$$

$$= \sum_{t = 0}^\infty t\mathbb{P}(T = t | X_0 = k)$$



$$= \sum_{t = 0}^\infty t\left(\mathbb{P}(T = t | X_0 = k, X_1 = k+1)\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k+1 | X_0 = k) \\ + \mathbb{P}(T = t | X_0 = k, X_1 = k-1)\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k-1 | X_0 = k) \right)$$

$$= \sum_{t = 0}^\infty t\left(\mathbb{P}(T = t | X_0 = k, X_1 = k+1)\mathbb{P}(Y_1 = 1) \\ + \mathbb{P}(T = t | X_0 = k, X_1 = k-1)\mathbb{P}(Y_1 = -1) \right)$$

Which is close, but not quite what is required.

Comment: @RB_1994, do you think my answer is correct? I don't really see why (how) your work could be useful.

Comment: I am finding it hard seeing how it works, I don't see where the one comes from. I was trying to attempt the question using the definition of conditional expectation.

Here is my understanding of your working.

$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_i \mathbb{E}(X | B_i) \mathbb{P}(B_i)$$ where $B_i$ are a partition of the sample space.

So, clearly $B_1 := X_1 = k+1$ and $B_2 := X_1 = k-1$ form a partition.

So $$\mathbb{E}(T|X_0 = k) = \mathbb{E}(T|X_0 = k, X_1 = k+1)\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k+1 | X_0 = k) + \mathbb{E}(T|X_0 = k, X_1 = k-1)\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k-1 | X_0 = k)$$

Could you continue from here?